# Returning custom object in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have written this query:

```
    private IDictionary<string, ReftableCache> Lookup(List<string> list)
    {
        var query = (from r in ReftableCached
                     where list.Contains(r.Description)
                     select new ReftableCache
                     {
                         RefTableName = r.RefTableName,
                         Reftable_K =  r.Reftable_K,
                         Description = r.Description
                     });
        return query.ToDictionary(r => r.Reftable_K, ????);
    }
```

But I have problem with the part in **????**
My goal is two have a dictionary, keyed by `Reftable_K` and the **value** pair of the key to be the object we created for it, but I can't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
return query.ToDictionary(r => r.Reftable_K, r => r);
```

You can also just use the overload that automatically returns the item as the value:

```
return query.ToDictionary(r => r.Reftable_K);
```

This makes `Reftable_K` the key, and the `ReftableCache` instance the value.

Comment: I assume you mean `r => r`, but is there a reason one can't use the overload @FarhadJabiyev refers to in his answer?

Comment: @lc. Mostly just because the OP was confused - Added that in as an option too.

Answer (score 4):

It must work for you: (*If you want to set the object itself as the value*)

```
  return query.ToDictionary(r => r.Reftable_K);
```

This overload of the `ToDictionary` takes an anonymous method as input. This anonymous method is actually a key selector that will select the key from the list and set it as the key in the dictionary object. For example, `Reftable_K` from the `ReftableCache` is selected as the key for the result in the dictionary and the **value** is the `ReftableCache` **object itself**.

*Additional*:

May be this method has confused you a bit. To make things more clear I want to explain one thing more. While creating a new dictionary we must specify the Key and the Value. In the example given above, the CLR automatically returns the instance of the object as value. If you want to specify the value as you want, you can add second anonymous function as input to the method. Like that:

```
return query.ToDictionary(r => r.Reftable_K, r => r);
return query.ToDictionary(r => r.Reftable_K, r => r.Column2);
// and so on...
```

Answer (score 4):

The `ToDictionary()` method takes two lambda expressions, the `key` and the `value`.
For both expressions you get the respective object from the collection as context.

So, you could try this:

```
private IDictionary<string, ReftableCache> Lookup(List<string> list)
{
    // execute the query
    var result = (from r in ReftableCached
                 where list.Contains(r.Description)
                 select new ReftableCache
                     {
                         RefTableName = r.RefTableName,
                         Reftable_K =  r.Reftable_K,
                         Description = r.Description
                     })
                 .ToList();

    // convert to dictionary 
    return result.ToDictionary(r => r.Reftable_K /*key*/
                              , v => v /*value*/);
}
```

You could also use the `new` object in the value part, for example:

```
return result.ToDictionary(r => r.Reftable_K /*key*/
                          , v => new ReftableCache
                                 {
                                     RefTableName = r.RefTableName,
                                     Reftable_K =  r.Reftable_K,
                                     Description = r.Description
                                 }  /*value*/);
```

Comment: *you can on the context of lambda expression the object of the collection, so, you will get You could try this*, what does that even mean?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say: "you have on the context...", I mean, in both cases (key and value), we can pass an expression where the lambda variable is a item of the collection.